# (Classname) has no attribute (attribute)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a DnD style dungeon crawler game. I'm using the 5E SRD and other publicly available information as the base for my characters and gameplay.
Currently I'm working on the character generator, and it seems to be going well, but I've hit a roadblock when trying to assign the racial bonuses. I've got the races set up as their own subclasses, each with it's unique bonuses. When I try to assign the appropriate bonuses based on the character's race I get a (Classname)has no attribute (attribute) error.

```
python
    class Race:
    def __init__(self, race):
        self.name = race
        self.racial_str_bonus = 0
        self.racial_char_bonus = 0


class Dragonborn(Race):
    def __init__(self):
        super()
        self.name = "Dragonborn"
        self.racial_str_bonus = +2
        self.racial_char_bonus = +1


def get_racial_bonus(race):
    race = race
    racial_str_bonus = 0
    racial_char_bonus = 0
    if race == "Dragonborn":
        racial_str_bonus = Dragonborn.racial_str_bonus
        racial_char_bonus = Dragonborn.racial_char_bonus
    return racial_str_bonus, racial_char_bonus


class BaseCharacter:
    def __init__(self, racial_str_bonus, racial_char_bonus):
        self.racial_str_bonus = racial_str_bonus
        self.racial_char_bonus = racial_char_bonus

    @classmethod
    def generate_player_character(cls):
        cls.race = input("Race: ")
        get_racial_bonus(cls.race)


BaseCharacter.generate_player_character()
```

What I'm looking for is something along the line of:

```
'''
Race: Dragonborn
print(my_player_char.racial_str_bonus)
2
'''
```

Where am I goofing up?

Comment: `Race(self)` is **not** how you invoke the inherited initialisation.

Comment: there are many problems with this code, please review how to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Yuca, I apologize if I made any faux pas. I thought I had provided a minimally reproducible example. I'm not understanding what you want me to do. I'm a novice programmer, so I appreciate any specific feedback.

Comment: @johnrsharpe: thanks for that pointer. As I mentioned to Yuca, I'm new to this. Most of my programming training came from the days of BASIC, so I'm trying to modernize my skills.

Comment: @Yuca, Thanks for the more specific feedback. I've tried to clean it up so it runs but still demonstrates the issue. Please let me know if there are more improvements needed.

Comment: Well, it's not really *minimal*, there's a lot of unnecessary stuff going on, but it's miles ahead of most new contributor questions, so I think a downvote is way too harsh. A minimal example would be something like maybe two class definitions, `Foo` and `Bar`, with `Bar` inheriting from foo, and you trying to initialize a `Bar` object and using one of it's attributes and getting the error. As jonsharpe pointed out, you are not invoking the super-class initializer. Which is why your subclass object lacks the attributes. As an aside, always use the generic [python] tag for all python questions

Comment: Also, if you are getting an error, always post the *full error message including the stack trace*. People don't want to run your code in their heads to see where the error is actually occurring, and a full traceback almost always tells you *exactly* where it is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone for the feedback. In cleaning up the code to get it minimally reproducible, I figured out the issue. Per Jonrsharpe's note, I corrected the inhertance invocation to 'super().**init**(self)'. Once that was correct, I realized that the way they had been defined, I had to include parentheses in the property call: "Dragonborn().racial_str_bonus".

Thanks again, and I will remember to improve my submissions in the future.